# Update gitlab repository imported from github

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository

I have a repository on github which once I finished I imported it to gitlab with new repository --> import project --> github and finally I selected the project to import
Then I updated the project on github but I can't get it to do it on gitlab too
Is there a way to pull changes to gitlab from this same repository?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to:

- clone your GitLab project locally
- add GitHub URL as a remote
- fetch the GitHub repository
- push to `origin` (GitLab)

That supposes:

- the [import process](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html) has preserved the SHA1 commit history from the original repository (GitHub) to GitLab
- you have not modified or added new commits to common branches (common to GitHub and GitLab)

---

Note: [GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#import-github-branch-protection-rules) (November 2022) improves the GitHub to GitLab import process with:

> ### Import GitHub branch protection rules
>
> When you import projects from GitHub to GitLab, GitHub branch protection rules that have an equivalent on GitLab are mapped to GitLab branch
> protection rules or project-wide GitLab settings:
>
> - GitHub rule **Require conversation resolution before merging for the project’s default branch** is mapped to the **All threads must be resolved**
>   GitLab setting.
> - GitHub rule **Require a pull request before merging** is mapped to the **No one** option in the **Allowed to push** list of the branch protection
>   rule.
> - GitHub rule **Require a pull request before merging - Require review from Code Owners** is mapped to the **Code owner approval** branch protection
>   rule. Requires GitLab Premium or higher.
> - GitHub rule **Require signed commits for the project’s default branch** is mapped to the **Reject unsigned commits** GitLab push rule.
>   Requires GitLab Premium or higher.
> - GitHub rule **Allow force pushes - Everyone** is mapped to the **Allowed to force push** branch protection rule.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html#branch-protection-rules), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/376683), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/371110), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/370951), [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/370949) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/370943).

And, still with [GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#import-pull-request-assigned-reviewers-from-github) (November 2022):

> ### Import pull request assigned reviewers from GitHub
>
> Previously, while importing projects from GitHub to GitLab, reviewers assigned to pull requests in GitHub were not imported as reviewers assigned
> to merge requests in GitLab.
>
> With this release, assigned reviewers are imported as assigned reviewers in GitLab. The following are out of scope for this release:
>
> - Review approval status.
> - Reviews requested from teams.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html#imported-data) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/355137).

---

And [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#import-github-repository-collaborators-as-gitlab-project-members) (March 2023) adds:

> ### Import GitHub repository collaborators as GitLab project members
>
> Until now, imported GitHub projects didn’t have their collaborators imported with them.
> This meant that no users had any permissions on these projects. As a workaround, group owners would add members before the import.
>
> Now, if a collaborator’s role can be mapped to a GitLab role, GitLab adds the GitHub collaborator to the imported project as a GitLab project member.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html#collaborators-members) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/388716).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the other answer would be to turn on [pull mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/pull.html) in GitLab so that it automatically updates.

Note: This is a paid feature, but paid features are available on public projects.